# Setting UILabel text to bold

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How do you set the text for a `UILabel` to bold in Swift programmatically? 
My code so far:

```
    var label = UILabel(frame:theFrame)
    label.text = "Foo"
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `UILabel`. Notice the `font` property.

Answer (score 293):

Use `font` property of `UILabel`:

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

or use default `system font` to bold text:

```
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

Comment: The second option is actually needed for me...thanks a ton..

Comment: love the second option, entering the font name using a string without autocomplete can sometimes be a ....!
 cheers bud.

Answer (score 18):

Use attributed string:

```
// Define attributes
let labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)
let attributes :Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : labelFont]

// Create attributed string
var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Foo", attributes:attributes)
label.attributedText = attrString
```

You need to define attributes.

Using attributed string you can mix colors, sizes, fonts etc within one text

Comment: Technically correct, but slightly overkill.

Comment: To expand on nhgrif's comment. NSAttributedString makes sense in this case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496093/making-text-bold-using-attributed-string-in-swift