# Automatically adjust Navigation Item Title font size to fit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

I have a `Navigation Bar` with a `Navigation Item Title`. I'm using a normal small title, not the iOS 13 large title.

On some screens the `Navigation Item Title` is too long, so it gets truncated with a trailing `…`

Is there a way to auto adjust the font size to fit the title in `Navigation Item Title`?

Comment: The navigation bar lets you insert `UILabel`, which means that you can automatically adjust the font size, I suppose.

Comment: Consider my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956561/how-to-resize-title-in-a-navigation-bar-dynamically/62043519#62043519 To work with normal titles you will have to set the font to ```UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)``` and ```largeTitleTextAttributes``` to ```titleTextAttributes```

Comment: And you will have to adjust this line ```tempLargeTitleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width > view.frame.width - 30``` (instead of 30 I use for normal titles 195). Inside the for-loop and in the end where you actually set your ```titleTextAttributes``` you have to set the font-weight to ```.semibold``` too.

Answer (score 4):

Place the code below in viewDidLoad(), this should scale down the size of the text in your title without truncating it.:

```
    let navbarTitle = UILabel()
    navbarTitle.text = "My nav title"
    navbarTitle.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    navbarTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    navigationItem.titleView = navbarTitle
```

Hopefully this helps you out. Play with the `minimumScaleFactor` to find a value you'd like to have. If you need the title to be bold: [How to make a UILabel bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025779/setting-uilabel-text-to-bold).

Additionally here's a link that might be of use to you: [Line break mode and number of lines on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762236/line-breaks-and-number-of-lines-in-swift-label-programmatically)